# Why failed to pause audio if pause event is registered using Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, knockout.js

I registered pause event using knockout on audio:

```
<audio data-bind="event: { pause: audioEnd }"></audio>
```

```js
self.audioEnd = function(data, event) {
    console.log('paused');
}
```

Then if you first call `$('audio').trigger('play')` and call `$('audio').trigger('pause')`, the audio cannot stop!

This problem has cost me a whole afternoon, and I figured out how to fix it: just add `return true` to `audioEnd`. I post this problem here in case someone else need it.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/d1uknpwv/)

---

One reason caused me so much time is that `trigger('play')` fires the `play handler` twice, which made me think there is one more call of `play`.

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/gttde0p0/)

I posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33670514/why-audio-triggerplay-fires-playhandler-twice-while-audio0-play)

Comment: If you want to solve your own question, please add the solution to the problem as a separate answer below.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agreed. but I am kind of waiting someone to give me an official answer this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Knockout events `preventDefault`. If you want the event processessing to continue after your event handler finishes, your handler should return true.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-action

Comment: Cool. Never thought that neglecting the 3rd note would cost me so much time.