# Why `$('audio').trigger(play)` fires playHandler twice while `$('audio')[0].play()` only fires once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, html5-audio

I used to think `trigger(play)` just fires the native `play` function of audio, but today I just noticed that there is a slight difference between these two methods. If you register a callback for `play`, e.g. `$('audio').on('play', function() { console.log('playing'); })`, the callback will be invoked twice if you use `trigger(play)` but only once when using `play()`.

- How come this discrepancy?
- Is it possible to make `trigger(play)` only fires the `play callback` once, so as to keep potential bugs away?

[[demo]](https://jsfiddle.net/Richard_Liu/gttde0p0/)

---

#### Update

In the demo, I call `trigger('play')` and `trigger('pause')` and then `play()` and `pause()`. The result is

```
// the following four lines are generated by trigger calls
play 
play
pause
pause
// the following two lines are generated by native calls
play
pause
```

This demo could illustrate what I'm talking about.

This problem could be reproduced on:

- Chrome version 46.0.2490.86 m
- IE 11.0.9600.18053
- FireFox 42.0

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Also please provide code in your question which illustrates the problem, not just a link to the demo. In your demo you have two calls to play which is why the file plays twice. Please also specify the browser you are testing in.

Comment: `trigger('play')` triggers your handler programmatically, which dispatches the play event on the audio element, once the clip starts playing, the play event is dispatched again, triggering your handler a second time, whereas `$('audio')[0].play()` won't trigger your handler initially, it'll trigger the dom element's native play event, which, when it starts playing will trigger your handler

Comment: @codecowboy Please see my update.

Comment: @billyonecan Cool. This answers my first question.